# NFC broadcast problem

Tags: android, broadcast, nfc

I really read 10 or 20 topics about that and unfortunately I didn't make it working. My receiver can capture broadcast but only if I send it via `sendBroadcast(intent)` from my app. I want it to capture broadcast from NFC adapter. F.e someone puts NFC Tag near my device and then my app should start or show in browsing menu, however that doesn't happen. Even if my app starts, and I put NFC Tag near device, it can't capture it, and in browsing menu I see other apps, which can. 
My receiver:

```
public class SomeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final String TAG = "SomeBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "Got intent: " + intent);    
}
}
```

And my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.nfc">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".broadcast.SomeBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/technologies"/>

        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>        
</receiver>

<activity android:name=".simulator.FakeTagsActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="TagViewer"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>        
</activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

In FakeActivity i have this lines:

`Intent exampleIntent = new Intent("android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED");
    sendBroadcast(exampleIntent);`

And when app reches them, my receiver captures intent, so I think that receiver is fine, but maybe I miss something in manifest? Are there special permission to capture global broadcast? Or should I start service or sth?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can't capture those intents with a BroadcastReceiver, because only Activities can receive NFC intents. You can find more information about it in the [NFC guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use technique described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781583/1224600) - it provides the same effect as a broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

According to here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320694/3736955), you cant catch NFC intent by BroadcastReceiver. The only way to handle it is by ForegroundDispatch and onNewIntent() function within activity. When NFC Tag is tapped, it looks for foreground activity to handle him.