# onNewIntent in Fragments in android

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am trying to develop a NFC application. I need to recognize the NFC TAG from the `OnNewIntent` that in the `Activity` class. Now I need to move and use fragments and not activity. Is their a way to replace the `onNewIntent` in the fragment class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320694/3736955), you cant catch NFC intent by BroadcastReceiver. The only way to handle it is by ForegroundDispatch and onNewIntent() function within activity. When NFC Tag is tapped, it looks for foreground activity to handle him.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best possible approach will be calling the setIntent() function on the received intent while executing onNewIntent() of an Activity and retreiving it back via getActivity().getIntent() during a fragment lifecycle.
Upd: 
Also you can use the pattern Observer to dispatch intent receiving events immediately to the registered fragments. Then you can obtain required data from getActivity().getIntent().

Comment: i tried that one, onResume(), it gets same intent (1st NFC tap) even there is no NFC is tapped again.

Comment: @JCodex, intent is always keeping through an activity lifecycle. Therefore, the last one will always be available in the onResume(). If i understood you question correctly.

Comment: yeah, so this approach is not good. Instead you need to get instance of fragment inside onNewIntent() and call funcion of fragment by sending NFC Tag info. That is my solution