# Hand down an Android Intent to another app

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way for an app to receive an Intent and "pass it down" to the next app?

My intention is the following: I would like to have my app receive the `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED` and `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` intents and examine their Extras to decide what to do with them: either trigger an action in the app, or ignore the Intent and hand it down to any other app that may be interested in it.

As I understand it, an `IntentFilter` will only work on the Intent's Action, Category or Data, but not on its Extras. Therefore I have to ensure my app gets all Intents, but to play nicely with other apps, I need to replicate this functionality manually.

Does Android provide a way for an app to tell it "I won't process the Intent you sent me, give it to someone else"? If not, what can I do? Resend the Intent from my app?

Comment: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research on the subject, it appears there's no easy way to accomplish this.

An `Intent` in Android can be addressed to three different recipient classes. This choice is made when sending the `Intent` and only instances of the matching recipient class will receive the `Intent`. Behavior differs based on the recipient class and the method called to send the `Intent`. See [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for details.

- If the `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` method is used, the recipient is an `Activity`. Only one `Activity` will receive the intent. If there is more than one `Activity` with a matching `IntentFilter`, a chooser dialog is typically displayed so that the user can make a choice. The chooser dialog, in turn, is triggered by another `Intent` with `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` as its action, acting as a wrapper around the original `Intent`. [(see code)](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=android%20Intent%20createChooser)
- If the `startService()` or `bindService()` method is used, a `Service` will receive the `Intent`. It is strongly encouraged (and for `bindService()` even enforced starting with API 21) to use these methods only on *explicit* Intents, which uniquely identify their component. Otherwise Android will pick a matching Service at random, and app developers have no control over that choice.
- If the `sendBroadcast()`, `sendOrdererdBroadcast()` or the (now deprecated) `sendStickyBroadcast()` method is used, a `BroadcastReceiver` will receive the intent. With `sendBroadcast()` the `Intent` will be sent to all matching receivers in a random order. With `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, recipients will be sent the broadcast one at a time. Upon registering a `BroadcastReceiver`, the app can set a priority for its `IntentFilter`, and those with higher priorities get the `Intent` first. In this particular case, any `BroadcastReceiver` in the queue can call `abortBroadcast()` upon receiving an `Intent` to prevent it from being propagated to recipients having a lower priority.

Now, as others have pointed out, `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED` and `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` are sent with `startActivity()` (or in a similar manner). Activities can use `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()` to bypass the chooser dialog and have all NFC Intents delivered to them, but that works only as long as the `Activity` is in the foreground.

NFC Intents are also special in how they are sent:

- Upon discovering an NDEF tag, Android will first try to send `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`.
- If there is no `Activity` with a matching `IntentFilter`, or if the tag is not an NDEF tag, Android will then try to send `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED`.
- If there is still no `Activity` with a matching `IntentFilter`, Android will finally try to send `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED`.

Activity Intents can be used to start a service or send a broadcast by implementing an "adapter" Activity which receives the `Intent`, triggers the desired action and then exits. However, there are still two major hurdles to overcome:

- If an NFC Intent is sent, only a foreground `Activity` is capable of intercepting it. In all other cases, if there are multiple potential recipients, Android will display the chooser and the app has no way to determine who gets the `Intent` – it may not even know there was one. Unless we are building our own distribution of Android (which we can tamper with in any way we want), we would likely have to intercept the `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` intent and extract the original `Intent` from its `EXTRA_INTENT` extra – but since `android.intent.action.CHOOSER` is also an `Intent` delivered to an `Activity`, we'd have the same issue of reliably intercepting it and forwarding what we're not interested in.
- Even for Intents received by the app, it has no easy ways to "pass down" those that it doesn't handle. At the most, it could replicate Android's behavior and re-send the Intents it does not handle. It would use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` or `PackageManager.resolveIntentActivities()` to determine the other recipients, as well as replicate the particular NFC Intent logic described above. This will only work if Android's security framework doesn't have any mechanisms to prevent random apps from sending NFC intents.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Android provide a way for an app to tell it "I won't process the Intent you sent me, give it to someone else"?

No.

Android does not allow you to "intercept" Intents before they get to other applications. If it did, you would get into the sticky situation of trying to decide which apps should get the Intent first before it bubbles down to other applications.

> If not, what can I do? Resend the Intent from my app?

For broadcast intents, you don't have to do anything. *Every* app that has registered an `intent-filter` to listen fo broadcasts will receive the broadcast.

Other Intents that will only be delivered to a single application- these are Intents that start Activities or Services. If there is any ambiguity about which application should receive one of these intents (i.e. multiple apps register intent filters that match the intent), Android will display the disambiguation UI asking the user to pick the app they want to use.

`android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED` and `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` fall into the latter bucket (as per [their documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)), and thus only one app will be able to receive those events and the user may be asked to choose which application to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have the following scenario: I have a tag and three apps with an IntentFilter for `TECH_DISCOVERED` in their manifest. When I'm in the home screen and scan the tag, I get the chooser dialog for the three apps. When I'm in one of the apps, the app in the foreground recognizes the tag, no chooser appears and, for all I know, the other apps never get to see the Intent. What's happening here? If the Intent is a broadcast, shouldn't all apps receive it, without a chooser being shown?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853622/android-nfc-tag-received-with-broadcastreceiver and its answers sound like the NFC intents are not broadcasts – which would be consistent with the behavior I'm seeing...

Comment: You are correct- I have updated my answer to reflect that. Only one application will be able to respond to NFC events, and the user gets to choose which application that is.